# Is Foreign Key Constraint mandatory? Why not just keep the key and not the constraint?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Is Foreign Key Constraint mandatory? Why not just keep the key and not the constraint?

For Eg:

```
class SalesOrderSummary(models.Model):

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    # Order Status values could : CONFIRMED, DISPATCHED, DELIVERED
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default='')


class SalesOrderItem(models.Model):
    """
     Line item details of the particular sales order, mostly they are grouped by seller, for easy processing
    """

    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    # Here I don't keep the ForeignKey Constraint, but I understand the constraint
    # and manage it myself, like whenever Order is deleted, these items are also 
    # getting deleted
    sales_order_id = models.BigIntegerField()

    seller_sku = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, default='')
    product_title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, blank=False, default='')
    quantity = models.BigIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default='0.00')
```

I totally agree that these FK Constraints, are here to make our life easy by making it to do our jobs. like automatically deleted when the associated main entity gets deleted. If I can manage that myself, then where is the problem. So let me know if I would encounter any dead end or something or some feature that's not at all possible.

Comment: Apart from the  constraint the foreign key adds  , also it is used in the select_related function  to access a salesorder  from a salesorderitem  because the framework  creates an inner join betwwen the two tables  to access the parent  object fast  , so without a foreign key you cant have that feature

Comment: Let me give you an analogy for your question: "Why should I use wheels when I can just drag my car along without them?" You basically speak about reinventing the wheel (that too as squares instead of circles) which already exist (and better than what you will come up with yourself).